# DRF: How to move lookup field at the end of URL while using @detail_route

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I am trying to make a @detail_route but the URL with default router is **/api/v1/stores/section/{id}/items/**

But I want to move lookup field at the end of URL like this **/api/v1/stores/section/items/{id}/**

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    serializer_class = TestSerializer

    @detail_route(methods=['get'])
    def items(self, request, pk=None):
```

Comment: You probably want a `list_route` instead of `detail_route` for such url patterns.

Comment: Using `list_route`, how can we get lookup field ?

Comment: @TasawerNawaz you can take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40659017/how-do-we-define-list-route-that-accept-arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not be able to do that without either pulling a specific url with Django url patterns as [shown in the tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/#binding-viewsets-to-urls-explicitly) or by [altering the router's code](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/routers.py#L117) to handle this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
@action(detail=True, url_path='/(?P<extra_id>[^/.]+)/')
def items(self, request, extra_id):
```

add this!

Caveat:

remove "/" if error else works

You might have to query for items object using 'extra_id'