# How do we define @list_route that accept arguments

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

In my application i have this `ModelViewSet` with one `@list_route()` defined function for getting list but with different serializer.

```
class AnimalViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list`, `create`, `retrieve`,
    `update` and `destroy` actions.
    """
    queryset = Animal.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AnimalSerializer // Default modelviewset serializer

    lookup_field = 'this_id'

    @list_route()
    def listview(self, request):
        query_set = Animal.objects.all()
        serializer = AnimalListingSerializer(query_set, many=True) // Serializer with different field included.
         return Response(serializer.data)
```

The Default `AnimalViewSet` with this `/api/animal/` end point yield this serialized data result as based on `AnimalSerializer` definition.

```
{
    "this_id": "1001",
    "name": "Animal Testing 1",
    "species_type": "Cow",
    "breed": "Brahman",
    ...
    "herd": 1
},
{
    "this_id": "1004",
    "name": "Animal Testing 2",
    "species_type": "Cow",
    "breed": "Holstien",
    ....
    "herd": 1
},
{
    "this_id": "1020",
    "name": "Animal Testing 20",
    "species_type": "Cow",
    "breed": "Brahman",
    ....
    "herd": 4
},
```

And the other one which is a `@list_route()` defined function named `listview` may have this end point `/api/animal/listview/` which yields this result as defined in `AnimalListingSerializer` structure.

```
{
    "this_id": "1001",
    "name": "Animal Testing 1",
    "species_type": "Cow",
    "breed": "Brahman",
    ....
    "herd": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "High Production",
        "description": null
    }
},
{
    "this_id": "1004",
    "name": "Animal Testing 2",
    "species_type": "Cow",
    "breed": "Holstien",
    ....
    "herd": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "High Production",
        "description": null
    }
},
{
    "this_id": "1020",
    "name": "Animal Testing 20",
    "species_type": "Cow",
    "breed": "Brahman",
    ....
    "herd": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Bad Production",
        "description": "Bad Production"
    }
}
```

**Now what i am trying to do is i want to define another `@list_route()` function that takes an argument and uses `AnimalListingSerializer` in order to filter the `query_set` result of the model object. A work around my help for a beginner like us**.

```
@list_route()
def customList(self, request, args1, args2):
        query_set = Animal.objects.filter(species_type=args1, breed=args2)
        serializer = AnimalListingSerializer(query_set, many=True)
         return Response(serializer.data)
```

Let us assumed that `args1 = "Cow"` and `args2 = "Brahman"`. And i am expecting this result.

```
{
    "this_id": "1001",
    "name": "Animal Testing 1",
    "species_type": "Cow",
    "breed": "Brahman",
    ....
    "herd": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "High Production",
        "description": null
    }
},
{
    "this_id": "1020",
    "name": "Animal Testing 20",
    "species_type": "Cow",
    "breed": "Brahman",
    ....
    "herd": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Bad Production",
        "description": "Bad Production"
    }
},
```

> But i know my syntax is wrong, but that is what i am talking about.
>   Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parameters in the view function are reserved for URL references. ie the route animals/5 would be passed to a view function that has pk as an argument.

```
def get(self, request, pk):
    # get animal with pk
    return animal with pk
```

You can pass parameters to your url via a query param ie

`/animals/listview/?speceis_type=cow&breed=braham`

then access it in your view using the request object 
`request.query_params['speceis_type']` and `request.query_params['braham']` or you can use the django rest filter middleware that is documented [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/)